# Get the Data horizontally rather than vertically

Tags: sql

Consider the query :

```
Select Dealer, Sales from DEALERDATA
where period in (201106,201107)
```

This will give result as:

```
DEALER SALES

Dealer1 100000
Dealer1 200000
Dealer2 600000
Dealer2 700000
```

I want result as

```
DEALER SALES SALES
Dealer1 100000 200000
Dealer2 600000 700000
```

If any one can let me know how this can be achieved?

Many thanks,
Sharon....

Comment: Which sql server are you using: mysql, ms sql, etc...?

Answer (score 1):

For a few number of columns you can use CASE combined WITH sum

```
SELECT Dealer
, SUM(CASE WHEN period=201106 THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) sales201106
, SUM(CASE WHEN period=201107 THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) sales201107
FROM DEALERDATA
WHERE period IN (201106,201107)
GROUP BY Dealer
```